# No matching factory method found:factory bean;factory method 'configurer()'.Check thatmethod with the specified name exists and that it is non-static

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing **Spring Boot Batch XML based approach**. In this example, I developed a `CommonConfig` like below. Somehow I wanted to use the XML based approach rather than using the annotation based approach for the Spring Batch.

**CommonConfig.java**

```
@StepScope
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.XXXX" })
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ImportResource({"classpath:jobs/ABC.xml"})
public class CommonConfig {

    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer configurer(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurer' defined in class path resource [com//config/CommonConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'commonConfig'; factory method 'configurer()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:547) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.jpaApplication.main(jpaApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this for about 1/2 hour and finally renamed my class from "Config" to "Configurations" and it worked.  Maybe there was another "Config" somewhere?  Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

The `EnableBatchProcessing` annotation will automatically add the `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` (and other beans) to your application context (See its javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html). So you don't need to define these beans yourself. What you need to do is to define your data source and it will be picked up by the `DefaultBatchConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.XXXX" })
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ImportResource({"classpath:jobs/ABC.xml"})
public class CommonConfig {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      // return your data source
   }


}
```

I would recommend following the getting started guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ to see how to correctly configure and run a Spring Batch job with Spring Boot.

Comment: I already went through many links and still its not working well.. Ideally combination of XML and Bean should work. It seems to be trouble to define EntityManager in XML if you've already define Annotation bean :(